# get accounts by territory for specific user

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I've been reviewing the territory management ERD and trying to get a handle on how to query for the accounts by territory assigned to a specific user.

In my controller, I'm using UserInfo.getUserId() to get the userId of the current user.

I need to get a list of accounts filtered by territory for that user.

Looking at the ERD, it looks like I need to to query the group table, but the Ids on the group table don't have any matches to the userId, so how do I get the relevant group ids for the specific user? How do I obtain a set of ids for a specific user that can be used to query on the accountShare table that should then return a list of accounts ids that are the accounts by territory for that user?

Am I traversing the objects correctly? I'm missing a relationship somewhere.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should look like something like this

1)

```
Map<Id,UserTerritory> UserTerritoryCurrentUserMap = new  Map<Id,UserTerritory>([Select u.UserId, u.TerritoryId, u.IsActive, u.Id  From UserTerritory u Where u.isActive=true and u.userId =: userId]);
```

2)

```
set<Id> TerritoryIdSet = new set<Id>();
for (UserTerritory ut:UserTerritoryCurrentUserMap.values()) {
    TerritoryIdSet.add(ut.TerritoryId);
}
```

3)

```
list<Group> map_group = [Select Id, RelatedId from Group where Type='Territory' AND RelatedId IN : TerritoryIdSet];
```

4)

```
List<AccountShare> lst_AccountShare = [Select Id, UserOrGroupId, AccountId from AccountShare where ( UserOrGroupId IN : map_group OR  UserOrGroupId =:userId )AND RowCause IN ('Territory', 'TerritoryManual', 'TerritoryRule')];
```

Comment: Hi @shimshon-korits. I have used your code for a number of time to get current user's territory and it's records. Thanks for great answers! I was wondering how can I get accounts from current user(u showed above) as well as it's child territories. Do I have to loop through accountshare? If yes can you point me to a documentation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Winter 15, you can use the new clause 'Using Scope' to filter record in a users assigned territories, provided your class is running this query with sharing/as the current user. So that,

> SELECT Id, Name FROM Account USING SCOPE My_Territory

will return all the account in the running user's territory. This should return accounts in child territories as well.

Help article on it here,
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000204543&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

@MnZ

Code above extended with support of child territories. Decide Yourself how many levels it should support by changing *noOfLevels* variable.  I hope some of You will find it usefull.

```html
Integer noOfLevels = 3;
Map<Id, UserTerritory> mIdTer = new Map<Id, UserTerritory>([Select UserId, TerritoryId, SystemModstamp, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, IsActive, Id From UserTerritory where  UserId = :userId]);

set<Id> TerritoryIdSet = new set<Id>();
for(UserTerritory ut:mIdTer.values()){
  TerritoryIdSet.add(ut.TerritoryId);
}

Territory[] nTers = new Territory[]{};
set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
parentIds.addAll(TerritoryIdSet);
for(integer i = 0 ; i < noOfLevels; i++){
 nTers = [select Id from Territory where ParentTerritoryId in :parentIds];
 if(nTers.size() > 0){
  parentIds = new Set<Id>();
  for(Territory t1 : nTers){
   TerritoryIdSet.add(t1.Id);
   parentIds.add(t1.Id);
  }
 } else {
  break;
 }
}


list<Group> map_group = [Select Id, RelatedId from Group where Type='Territory' AND RelatedId IN : TerritoryIdSet];

List<AccountShare> lst_AccountShare = [Select Id, UserOrGroupId, AccountId from AccountShare where ( UserOrGroupId IN : map_group OR  UserOrGroupId =:userId )AND RowCause IN ('Territory', 'TerritoryManual', 'TerritoryRule')];

Map<Id, Account> mId2acc = new Map<Id,Account>();

for(AccountShare a1 : lst_AccountShare){
 mId2acc.put(a1.AccountId, null);
}

mId2acc = new Map<Id, Account>([select Id, Target_Call__c  from Account where Id in: mId2acc.keySet()]);
```

Comment: If this was in response to the question posed in the comments, it would be better to either 1) Ask the OP to post it as a separate question so you can answer it or (since it's been 2 years) 2) post the comment as your own question, give credit in your question to @MnZ, and self-answer the question. That way people who have that question can actually find your answer. As it is, your answer is considered to be in response to the original question.

Comment: I feel like that's a little harsh. Technically this is an answer to the original question... Just a more extensive one, fully coded, with an extra feature.